# good application to detect drive failures

Tags: hard-drive, sata, smart

Right now, i've got a machine with several drives in it, of various size/make, in various configurations.  I'm running Windows 2008R2 server.

Every once in a while, i will hear one of the drives click intermittently, but I don't know which one (I cannot manually reproduce the problem, though it happens all the time).  The configuration is so convoluted that my ability to actually boot and run the system properly without one or more drives is difficult at best so I can't localize the problem. I'm positive its a hard drive and not a fan or CDROM or something.

S.M.A.R.T. is enabled in my bios, though NOTHING has been throwing any errors.  Any drive scanning tool i've run has failed to spot any problems - yet the clicking continues.

Can someone suggest a util/approach to find out whats going on?

Comment: Have you tried tools that show the SMART parameters?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [SpinRite](http://www.grc.com/spinrite.htm)?

Comment: Great program. Some drive makers have their own tools as well. Check the web site of the maker for diag tools.  I know Western Digital and Seagate both have them.